# What design pattern to use for updating NSManagedObjects from web server data

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to do this efficiently and I am wondering what the standard design pattern is, to basically sync objects from MYSQL to core data.

I am thinking:
1. Send the objects from MYSQL as JSON
2. As I am iterating through each JSON object, pull the corresponding object from core data, and delete, and just insert the new one with the updated attributes.

My concern is that this will require a trip to the DB at every loop (slowing down I imagine).

So I figured I could iterate through JSON results and pull all the names I want to pull from CD. Then make a massive CD query with that array of names. Then I would delete these, and just insert the new ones.  But I think the massive query would take a while.

What do you guys think, what is the best approach, or a different approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use your first approach and just commit to the database every 100 records for example.

Comment: Im more worried about loading from DB every iteration

Answer (score 0):

I think that an approach similar to that described in
[Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4) in the "Core Data Programming Guide"
should work here:

- Sort the JSON objects by some unique id that is also stored in the database (or make the
  server return the objects in sorted order).
- Perform a fetch request for all items in the database, sorted by the same id. Perhaps set a batch size for the fetch request.
- Traverse in parallel through both lists (the JSON objects and the fetched items). This allows to detect new, updated and deleted objects in one single loop over all entries.

If the number of entries is very large, it might be necessary to save the context in-between, or to use explicit autorelease pools to limit the memory storage.